# Why would models exported from Blender and imported into Unity3d have similar convex meshes?

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I'm creating a dice based game in Unity3d. I've created the DnD style dice in Blender (no numbers, yet, but have radiused the edges).

The issue I'm having is that when I have all the models in the same blender project, but export them separately as .fbx files, all objects seem to have convex meshes similar to the tetrahedron, causing the mesh collider to not line up with all the faces. This results in the dice sinking into the "floor".

In Blender, the meshes appear to be correct (i.e., in Edit mode, the vertices/edges/faces seem to be what you'd expect). Is it possible to create multiple meshes in Blender, but correctly export them into unity individually?

I'd rather not have to recreate shaders in multiple Blender files.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I don't clearly understand. Do you mean that meshes have radiused edge, but colliders don't? Maybe you can provide a screenshot?

Comment: @Nikolai I've added a clarifying picture. When I create a mesh collider on anything with more faces than a tetrahedron, and set the mesh collider to convex, the convex mesh collider only has 4 faces and is always weirdly skewed between vertices.

Comment: @MickyD I do know that, but importing the Blender file directly will have all the objects in it. Will they be imported as discrete objects or one single chunk of objects?

Comment: @MickyD I'd thought about that, but then if I have procedural shaders, I'd have to recreate them in each blender file.

Comment: Ah good point. No worries good sir :)